# How to add text box in configurable product page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, php-7

[image]

Just like shown in image above.Is this possible with magento dashboard functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file as Module/Namespace/Setup/InstallData.php and add the following code then

```
<?php 
  namespace Module\Namespace\Setup;

    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     * $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create([
            'setup' => $setup
        ]);

        /** @noinspection PhpUnnecessaryFullyQualifiedNameInspection */
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'is_feature', [
                'group'                   => 'Product Details',
                'type'                    => 'int',
                'backend'                 => '',
                'frontend'                => '',
                'label'                   => 'Is Feature',
                'input'                   => 'select',
                'source'                  =>
                    'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'visible'                 => true,
                'default'                 => '0',
                'frontend'                => '',
                'unique'                  => false,
                'note'                    => '',
                'required'                => false,
                'sort_order'              => '',
                'global'                  =>
                    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\
                    ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_on_front'        => true
            ]);
    }
}
```

After that run below command

```
sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento clear:cache
```

Comment: Is this possible make text-box attribute in  configurable product by only use dashboard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for this.Login Your Back end go to catalog-> Product-> Open any product -> Customizable Option.Please find the attached screenshot.[image]

my final product page look like
[image]

Thanks Everyone for their help.